# Subseting df rows based on the column they reach maximum in

Tags: r

I am having a difficult time figuring how to subset my df to pull out all of the rows that reach there maximum in the same columns.

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)  
X0 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
X30 <- c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)  
X60 <- c(9,10,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)  
X90 <- c(8,9,10,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)  
X120 <- c(7,8,9,10,6,5,4,3,2,1)  
mydata <- data.frame(ID, X0, X30, X60, X90, X120)
```

For above data set, here is the output

```
   ID X0 X30 X60 X90 X120  
1  1  1  10   9   8    7
2  2  2   9  10   9    8
3  3  3   8   8  10    9
4  4  4   7   7   7   10
5  5  5   6   6   6    6
6  6  6   5   5   5    5
```

The first thing I tried was to arrange the data

```
order <- arrange(mydata, X0, X30, X60, X90, X120)
```

Output:

```
    ID X0 X30 X60 X90 X120
1   1  1  10   9   8    7
2   2  2   9  10   9    8
3   3  3   8   8  10    9
4   4  4   7   7   7   10
5   5  5   6   6   6    6
6   6  6   5   5   5    5
```

This orders my larger df so I can create a heat map looks like this.

[image]

I would like to then subset my df and pull out any genes (rows) that peak at column X0, X.5, etc. Does anyone know a way to do this?

I know this is a terribly worded question with blithe detail, I am having trouble generating an example that will work. But if anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Is this what you want? `mydata[apply(mydata[,2:6], 2, which.max),]`

Comment: akrun, I spent time trying to figure out what the best output would be, is it possible to generate df's with all the rows that peak at each column?

Comment: Reese, the error I get when I insert your code is "Error: unexpected ')' in "mydata[apply[,2:6], 2, which.max)" "

Answer (score 0):

I it worked using

```
max.col(mydata[2:9], "first")
```

and aligning it to the data frame.